# Can I use Cron to schedule a daily commit on macOS?

Tags: git, macos, terminal, cron

I'm currently working on a project that I'd like to commit to a repo on a daily basis as a tertiary backup. I've written the following little script to quickly commit my changes for the day:

```
REPO_PATH="/Users/niekvandepas/my-project"
git -C "$REPO_PATH" add -A
git -C "$REPO_PATH" commit -m "`date`"
```

The script works as expected, committing my changes for the day with a timestamp. Now I'd like to be able to automatically run this script on a daily basis. I tried using `cron` for this, but I'm running into an issue regarding (I think) directory or file permissions.

I've put the above script in `/usr/local/bin/commitscript.sh` and have verified that it still works. I then added the following line to my user crontab (`crontab -e`, no `sudo`):

```
0 10 * * * /usr/local/bin/commitscript.sh > /tmp/cron.log 2> /tmp/cron.err
```

However, when 10:00 comes around, my changes are not committed, and `/tmp/cron.err` has the following lines:

```
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: Operation not permitted
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: Operation not permitted
```

I'm assuming both of these are fatal git errors, for `git add` and `git commit`, respectively. This is confusing to me, since it's my user crontab, and the git repo resides in my home directory. Any ideas?

By the way, I'm running macOS Big Sur 11.4 and have granted iTerm full disk access.

Comment: Probably it's run with a working directory that your user doesn't have access to, try `cd`ing into a known good directory before running `git`

Comment: Hmm, `cd`ing into the project directory seems to work fine, it's only the `git` commands that give me trouble.

Comment: Did you try to give access to `cron` itself as you did with iTerm (e.g. full disk access)?

Comment: @Matt I checked that, but I don't see `cron` requesting FDA in the security & privacy settings.

Comment: Try to add it manually to see if the error persists. Since the cron jobs run in the background, the entry might not get added to the list automatically.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I totally missed the fact you can manually add executables to the list. Granting `/usr/sbin/cron` Full Disk Access fixed it. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Cheers

Comment: You *did* say *tertiary backup*, implying you already have primary and secondary ones, so this comment has little value, but I'd just like to note that Git is not a very good backup system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to manually give the `cron` executable the required access as you did with iTerm. This is sometimes necessary because the cron jobs run in the background and might need to be authorised themselves to access certain resources.

To grant `/usr/sbin/cron` Full Disk Access, you can open *System Preferences*, navigate to *Security & Privacy*, select *Privacy* in the tab-bar and select *Full Disk Access* on the left sidebar. Then click the <kbd>+</kbd> button, search & select the executable `/usr/sbin/cron` and click *Open*.

This will add an entry in the list of apps and your cronjob should now have the required permissions. Here is a screenshot of the panel in the System Preferences:

[image: screenshot-of-settings]

Comment: Just pointing out that if you can't see the `/usr/sbin` folder when trying to give permission, you can Cmd+Shift+G to directly type the folder location https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/83006